# How to increase / decrease value in minecraft bossbar without entering a specific number 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hello I am working on my first minecraft map! But I don't know how to decrease / increase a number in the bossbar, without entering a specific number, instead, for example, incrementing by 1.

I am using version 1.16.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bossbars don't support math operations directly. Instead, you'll have to use a scoreboard to manage your bossbars.

I usually create an objective named `bossbar` for my bossbars, and use fake player names as descriptors.

```
scoreboard objectives add bossbar dummy [{"text":"Bossbar Values"}]
```

We need a repeating command block with the following command. This will make the bossbar use the scoreboard value.

```
execute store result bossbar minecraft:myBossbar value run scoreboard players get myBossbar bossbar
```

Then, all you need to do is increment the scoreboard and the value in the bossbar will change automatically. Use the following command to decrease bossbar by 5:

```
scoreboard players remove myBossbar bossbar 5
```

Comment: Thank you for anwsering. But I have a problem. I have typed out & edited the command. But it will remove every single value from my bossbar. I tried adding 10 but nothing has happened. I have checked the command block and it has outputed this error: Can't get value of bossbar for minecraft:xp; none is set.

Comment: @WolfPlay013 I think you accidentally tried to get the bossbar value, not the scoreboard value. The command in the command block should take the scoreboard value and store it in the bossbar, not the other way round.

Comment: I have just realized my mistake. It wasn't what you have said. I have typed out in the execute store result bossbar minecraft:myBossbar
                                                              ^
the bossbar name instead of the set nickname. It now works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question: 
Use `/bossbar set <id> value <value>` to change the value. 
 Example: `/bossbar set bsb1 value 50`

Use `/bossbar set <id> max <max>` to set the maximum value (defualt is 100, you do not have to change this)

Comment: OP wanted to increment/decrement the bossbar value without setting a specific value.

Comment: If that is what OP means, perhaps the question could be clarified? What number is OP referring to? the value? Does OP want it to decrease/increase by a set value when the command is used?

Comment: Hello. This isn't what i mean. I mean that it will decrease the number like 10-5 and if the value is 8 it would decrease by 5 even tough there is 8 instead of 10. This will work for a lot of numbers instead of just one.